# What does Jacobian mean in this compactification context?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, compactification

Referring to Pg. 2 and 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3809): the advection equation
$$
\partial_tu + \partial_xu = 0
$$
under the compactifying coordinates
$$
\rho(x) = \dfrac{x}{1+x}
$$
becomes
$$
\partial_tu + (1-\rho)^2\partial_\rho u = 0.
$$
Then a time coordinate transformation is introduced,
$$
\tau = t - \bigg(x + \dfrac{C}{1 + x}\bigg).
$$
So I'm confused by the following sentence: "With the compactification we get the Jacobian
$$
\begin{split}
\partial_\tau &= \partial_t\\
\partial_x &= (-1+C\Omega^2)\partial_\tau + \Omega^2\partial_\rho,
\end{split}
$$
where $\Omega:=(1-\rho)$." What does the Jacobian here refer to? It doesn't make sense to me that it is the Jacobian matrix and determinant ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the therm Jacobian is used here as synonymous of [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of the function $u$ that, with the given substitutions becomes:
$$
u(t,x)=u\left(\tau+\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}+C(1-\rho),\frac{\rho}{1-\rho}\right)
$$

So, for the total derivative (that is a $2\times 1$ matrix) we have:
$$
(\partial_\tau,\partial_\rho)=\left(\partial_t\frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau}+\partial_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau},\partial_t\frac{\partial t}{\partial\rho}+\partial_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial\rho}     \right)
$$

that, with a bit of algebra, gives:

$
\partial_\tau=\partial t
$

$
\partial_\rho=\partial_x \frac{1}{(1-\rho)^2}+\partial_t \left(\frac{1}{(1-\rho)^2} -C \right)
$

From which we have your final result.